# Dealing with strings in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

As part of some beginner c++ template exercises, I'm trying to write a template as a wrapper for std::vector in c++, and I've come across a snag.

Say the types of variables I'll be using are int, double and string.

I'm trying to write a loop to fill in the vector:

```
type element;

while (element != 0){
  std::cout << "Enter an element, use 0 to exit: ";
  std::cin >> element;

  if(element != 0)
    items.push_back(element);
}
```

The problem is, while this works for int & double, it doesn't work with std::string, as string doesn't support !=. I can also see myself having problems with working out the largest/small value in the vector.

What is the best way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide an optional template argument which is a comparator (I think the standard lib does that frequently). Less ambitiously, you could use type{} to compare against which should work for anything with a default ctor: `if(element != type{})`. (Your problem is not that string doesn't have a comparison operator but that the operators aren't defined for comparisons with ints).

Comment: Could you please clarify on the optional template argument with an example or a link to some code?

Comment: E.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/34569/. googling "c++ optional comparator template parameter" or so gives lots of links, but it's sometimes hard to find authoritative sources. Some standard library doc or tutorial should be helpful. For optional template params in general cf. https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fdefault_args_for_templ_params.htm.

Comment: +1, though IMHO it's more direct and intuitive to accept a *sentinel* value and compare using the normal `!=`: `while (element != sentinel)` - one benefit is that the sentinel value can be streamed in the prompt: `...use " << sentinel << " to exit: "...`